# Camera buttons not working in Galaxy s

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm using the following code to open the camera activity

```
public void callTakeVideo(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriVideo);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This will open the android camera and I'm able to capture the video and save it without any problem the first time. But when I open the camera again the buttons in the camera view are not working.

**This problem exists only in galaxy s. How to fix it?

Comment: In what way are the buttons not working?

Comment: if u tap the save button ,nothing happens!

Comment: @Fredrik Mork: I hadn't disabled the buttons. Also this is working fine for the nexus, defy and milestone. In galaxy s only for the first time i'm able to save the video.